# Authenticating FOS user outside of Symfony

Tags: php, swift, symfony, fosuserbundle, perfect

I am developing an API that needs to work with an existing Symfony installation. The API is written in Swift using Perfect.

I've determined that Symfony uses the FOS user bundle and MessageDigest encoder (aka SHA 512 hashing).

Looking at the sources, I can see that FOS generates a random bytes salt.
I can see this salt value (32 char long hex string) stored in the user table in the db.

I then went ahead and implemented the encoding process that I see on the following link, in Swift (note, I include hardcoded salt value taken from the db and the matching password).

[MessageDigestPasswordEncoder.php](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Encoder/MessageDigestPasswordEncoder.php)

```
@IBAction func calculate(_ id: AnyObject?) {
        let raw = "1234"
        let salt = "6bf3brej22cc8g0go04ck44g0co484c"

        let salted = "\(raw){\(salt)}"

        var digestData = salted.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)?.sha512()
        var digest = digestData!.toHexString()

        for _ in 0..<5000 {
            digestData = "\(digest)\(salted)".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)?.sha512()
            digest = digestData!.toHexString()
        }


        let encodedPass = digestData!.base64EncodedString()

        NSLog("encodedPass: \(encodedPass)")
    }
```

Unfortunately, the result I get is not the same string as the encoded string stored in the DB.

I cannot find any error in my code unless FOS is not using the exact same salt string that is stored in the database.

I'd appreciate any help from FOS / Symfony users on what I'm doing wrong or how I could possibly go about debugging this.

Answer (score 1):

So, I've found the solution by importing the CommonCrypto lib. (via custom module.modulemap) instead of using a third-party framework for the SHA512 hashing (that I was using):

```
func calculateCommonCrypto() {
    let raw = "1234"
    let salt = "6bf3brej22cc8g0go04ck44g0co484c"

    let salted = "\(raw){\(salt)}"

    let saltedData = NSData(data: salted.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
    var digest = [UInt8].init(repeating: 0, count: Int(CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH))

    CC_SHA512(saltedData.bytes, CC_LONG(saltedData.length), &digest)

    var combinedData = NSMutableData()
    let saltedBytes = NSData(data: salted.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)

    for _ in 1 ..< 5000 {
        combinedData.append(&digest, length: digest.count)
        combinedData.append(saltedBytes.bytes, length: saltedBytes.length)

        CC_SHA512(combinedData.bytes, CC_LONG(combinedData.length), &digest)

        combinedData = NSMutableData()
    }

    let finalData = Data(bytes: digest)

    let encodedStr = finalData.base64EncodedString()
}
```